# Printing the lowest and second lowest values in an array using methods (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and have been given an assignment that asks:

**Description**

A group of friends decide to run the Boston Marathon. Their names and times (in minutes) are below:

```
Name       Time(minutes)

Elena       341
Thomas      273   
Hamilton    278 
Suzie       329 
Phil        445 
Matt        402
Alex        388
Emma        275
John        243
James       334
Jane        412
Emily       393
Daniel      299   
Neda        343 
Aaron       317    
Kate        265
```

Find the fastest runner. Print the name and his/her time (in minutes).

Find the second fastest runner. Print the name and his/her time (in minutes).

**Instructions**

Write a method that takes as input an array of integers and returns the index corresponding to the
person with the lowest time. Run this method on the array of times. Print out the name and time
corresponding to the returned index.
Write a second method to find the second‐best runner. The second method should use the first method
to determine the best runner, and then loop through all values to find the second‐best (second lowest)
time.
Here is a program skeleton to get started:

```
class Marathon {
 public static void main (String[] arguments){
 String[] names ={
 "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
 "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
 "Aaron", "Kate"
};
 int[] times ={
 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299,
 343, 317, 265
 };
 int i1 = fastestIndex(times);
 int i2 = secondFastestIndex(times);
 //
 // your output based on the index i1 and i2
 //
 }
 // your two Java methods:
 // fastestIndex() and secondFastestIndex()
}
```

I wrote a program that prints the first and second place times and names but now I am starting to think I didn't follow the instructions correctly. Could anyone help me figure out what I should do differently?

Here is my amateur code:

```
public class Lab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] names = {
            "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", 
            "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate"
        };

        int[] times = {
            341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265
        };

        int firstplace = times[0];
        String firstname = names[0];

        int secondplace = times[0];
        String secondname = names[0];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < times.length; counter++)
        {
            if (times[counter] < firstplace) {
                firstplace = times[counter];
                firstname = names[counter]; }
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < times.length; counter++)
        {
            if (times[counter] > firstplace)
                if (times[counter] < secondplace) {
                    secondplace = times[counter];
                    secondname = names[counter]; }
        }
            System.out.printf("The fastest runner is: %s (%d Minutes)%n", firstname, firstplace);
            System.out.printf("The second fastest runner is: %s (%d Minutes)%n", secondname, secondplace);
        } // end main
    } // end class Lab
```

This is what it prints:

```
The fastest runner is: John (243 Minutes)
The second fastest runner is: Kate (265 Minutes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the complete answer you want is this:

Your teacher gives you specific pseudo-code on how to solve this problem and you should follow it.

> Write a method that takes as input an array of integers and returns the index corresponding to the person with the lowest time.

this is it: `public static int fastestIndex(int[] times){...}`
it is `static` because it is not an instance method (meaning you don't have to create an instance of an object to call it)

and the second one also has the same signature

```
public static int secondFastestIndex(int[] times)
```

and inside it calls the first method to help find the second fastest index

then you print both.

Here is the full code

```
public class Lab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String[] names = {
                "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", 
                "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate"
            };

            int[] times = {
                341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265
            };



            int win = fastestIndex(times);
            int second = secondFastestIndex(times);
            System.out.printf("The fastest runner is: %s (%d Minutes)%n", names[win], times[win]);
            System.out.printf("The second fastest runner is: %s (%d Minutes)%n", names[second], times[second]);
    } // end main



    public static int fastestIndex(int[] times) 
    {

        int fastestIndex = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < times.length; counter++)
        {

            if (times[counter] < times[fastestIndex]) 
            {
                fastestIndex = counter;
            }
        }

        return fastestIndex;

    }

    public static int secondFastestIndex(int[] times)
    {
        int fastestIdx = fastestIndex(times);
        int secondFastestIdx = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < times.length; counter++)
        {
            //you search for the fastest, but you ignore it if it is
            // equal to the fastest index (so you are really finding the 2nd)
            if (times[counter] < times[secondFastestIdx] && counter != fastestIdx) 
            {
                secondFastestIdx = counter;
            }
        }

        return secondFastestIdx;
    }

} // end class Lab
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the response this was very helpful. I think there was a concept I was missing and so I've been reading the textbook along with your code to understand this better. Right now my code is compiling but when I run it in command prompt it hangs with no output.

Comment: @presence do you need any further help? the code I posted above runs in my eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an assignment I cannot tell you the exact code, but here is what you can do.
It is a better idea to break your code into functions that perform specific tasks and this is what your starter code says. You need to write two functions fastestIndex and secondFastestIndex. The fastestIndex is the function that should return the fastestIndex and secondFastestIndex should return the second fastest index, so just structure you code so that the code that performs the task for fastestIndex is in the corresponding method (you can do this by just moving the current fragment of the code to new method) and same for secondFastestIndex and then call both of them from the main method.
This is the best I could explain. Basic skeleton should be like this:

```
void main() {
   // do some task;
   // call fastestIndex;
   // call secondFastestIndex;
}

int fastestIndex() {
   // code 
     int firstplace = times[0];
     String firstname = names[0];
     for (int counter = 0; counter < times.length; counter++)
        {
            if (times[counter] < firstplace) {
                firstplace = times[counter];
                firstname = names[counter]; }
        }
     // return stuff
}

//Same for secondFastestIndex
```

Just work around to restructure a code like the skeleton and you will be fine. *Also make sure to call fastestIndex from secondFastestIndex to avoid redundancy and completely follow the instructions.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have largely missed the instruction in the problem.

> The second method should use the first method to determine the best runner, and then loop through all values to find the second‐best (second lowest) time.

That clearly means that `secondFastestIndex()` should first invoke `fastestIndex()`,  and then use the returned value to evaluate the second fastest runner, which I don't see in your code. Here is the kind of implementation that should satisfy it:

```
int secondFastestIndex(){
   //...
   fastestRunnerIndex = fastestIndex()
   //Run loop again on the array and ignore the fastestRunnerIndex while finding the smallest number in it.
   return secondFastestRunnerIndex;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was looking at the code written by the OP not the code in the instructions. My bad. I'll just delete my other comment as it's totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider also the case when the fastest is in place one. Then, you cannot equal `secondfastestIndex` to `0` in the first place. 
(For example, in the case of 70, 250, 300, 450). Pay attention to the method to find the second fastest. Previous comments are wrong in terms of `secondFastest`

```
package mitJava2010;

public class As3_Marathon {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James",
                "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };
        int[] times = { 70, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
        }

        int f = findTheFastest(times);
        int sf = find2fastest(times);
        System.out.println("The fastest is " + names[f] + " with " + times[f] + " minutes");

        System.out.println("The second fastest is " + names[sf] + " with " + times[sf] + " minutes");
    }

    private static int find2fastest(int[] times) {
        int f = findTheFastest(times);
        int sf = (f != 0) ? 0 : 1;
        for (int i = sf + 1; i < times.length; i++) {
            if (times[i] < times[sf] && i != f)
                sf = i;

        }
        return sf;
    }

    private static int findTheFastest(int[] times) {
        int minIn = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < times.length; i++) {
            if (times[i] < times[minIn])
                minIn = i;
        }
        return minIn;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The search is fine. Just put them as a methods and call those methods from the main program. The instructions specified to call methods.

Put the firstplace searching loop in a method "firstplace(int [] times)" and carry out the first place searching in this method. And the do the same for the second place as well.

I am new to programming and this was what I felt would make the code follow the instructions.